# c# How to build a custom DataView from a DataTable?

Tags: c#, datatable, ado.net, dataview

I need to create a DataView from a DataTable, but with an unusual twist:

I need to decide (with code) on a row-by-row basis which rows in the DataTable are included in the DataView.

```
DataTable dt = LoadData();
DataView dv = new DataView(dt);

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    if (RowIsGood(row))
    { 
        // This obviously doesn't work but I need equivalent logic:
        DataRowView drv = new DataRowView();
        drv.Row = row;
        dv.Add(drv);
    }
}
```

Some important things to note:

1. The code in the RowIsGood function above is too complicated to replicate using the standard RowFilter method.
2. The DataTable has the potential to be very large.  It is also referenced by multiple grid controls.  Adding temporary columns to the DataTable to facilitate a RowFilter operation is not possible.
3. I'm using .NET v4.0.

Is then even possible with the DataTable/DataView architecture?

Does LINQ allow me to customize a DataView like I need?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The requirements are more than a little vague, but I would avoid that approach.  You could add one or more columns to the DT which summarize the various condition which are too complicated.  The goal would be to get some level of primitive values which you *can* use in a RowFilter.

Comment: I would think creating a reduced table with "RowIsGood" results should work? Something like "DataTable reducedDt = dt.Clone(); and then in the for loop, if (RowIsGood){ reducedDt.ImportRow(row);} and then after the loop, "DataView dv = new DataView(reducedTable);" Or am I missing something?

Comment: Have you considered `DataView.Delete` and not call AcceptChanges? Those rows stay simply go into a deleted state and are hidden (until you want them back, then you can reject the changes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are looking for a row by row solution and already have a function that takes a DataRow and returns a bool.

Simply add the refernce to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions`
And use the `AsDataView` Method

```
DataView dv=DT.AsEnumerable().Where(RowIsGood).AsDataView();
```

Answer (score 2):

```
DataView dv = (from n in DT.AsEnumerable() Where RowIsGood(n) select n ).AsDataView();
```